# AS3 Associating Sound Volume within Timer Class

Tags: actionscript-3

How to associated sound volume linearly reduced/increased along timer class.

I just want my sound stop on its half of total duration within fading out effect smoothly.

I use bellow class but no sound fade out:

```
var _mysound: mysound = new mysound();
var mysoundchannel: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var soundtimer: Timer = new Timer(1000, count);
var count: Number = 1;
var vol = mysoundchannel.soundTransform.volume;

bt_.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click)
function _click(event: MouseEvent): void {
    soundtimer.start();
    mysoundchannel = _mysound.play();
    soundtimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _timer)
    function _timer(event: TimerEvent): void {  
        vol = Number((count) - soundtimer.currentCount);
        if (vol ==1) {
            vol -= 0.05;
            mysoundchannel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(vol, 0.0);
        }
        soundtimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _timer)
        mysoundchannel.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Once it reaching targeted volume level at `TIMER_COMPLETE`"_ Try a logic like `if (sound_volume <= target_volume) { then stop or remove the Timer listener }`

Comment: Do **trace** the **vol** variable every time you change the volume and the time you stop the sound, and you'll understand why it doesn't work.